# R won't recognize updated CSV

Tags: r, read.csv

so this is a super basic question that I'm hoping someone can help me with (I'm super new to R, so my troubleshooting is remedial at best).

I noticed there were some spelling errors in my data, so I went back to the CSV file, made the changes to the file, saved, closed out, and re-read in the data using read.csv(). Everything showed up and worked as normal until I wanted to simply run a count of the entries in three of the columns (I've done this numberous times with the exact same code and exact same CSV file with the exact same working directory, no spelling errors), but for whatever reason I got the following error message:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'FFS_TargetingEventsAllCSV2.csv': No such file or directory

I restarted everything, reset the working directory, doublechecked spelling and used getwd(), but encountered the same problem.

So I decided to use an older backup version of the same dataset. I was able to read it in as normal, and I was able to run my counts. However, I noticed there were similar spelling errors. So I went back to the CSV, made the necessary changes, re-read in the CSV. Everything looked normal until I ran the counts again and saw the exact same spelling errors, unchanged.

So I decided to start fresh and re-save the file (Save As) under a new name, new CSV, same working directory...same. exact. issue.

Every time I opened the CSV file on my desktop, it shows me the most up to date version, but I can't figure out why R isn't recognizing any changes. I even made new, subtle spelling changes in a different column to see if that would make a difference, but nope.

To clarify, the data in the three colums of interest are just 2-3 letters (i.e. FSP). It's only text, sometimes with a hypthen (i.e. HTBR-DA). I'm not trying to run any stats/tests or anything, I just want summary statistics. I also updated my R/RStudio last Thursday, so I have the most recent version of the software as well.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error message is telling you that it cannot find the file. Probably the file is not in the current working directory. The `getwd()` function will tell you what your current working directory is. The `file.choose()` function will let you browse the file list in that directory and change to other directories to look for it.

Comment: Did you open the CSV file in Excel and perhaps save it as an XLSX file, not a CSV? Or maybe did you type "yourfile.csv" and selected CSV format and it's saved as "yourfile.csv.csv"? Make sure your operating system is showing you full file names with extensions. You can use `list.files()` in the directory to see what R sees as the available files.

Comment: I've checked getwd() multiple times, and it is set to the correct location. I've also restarted R and re-set the working directory a few times to try that as well.

For some reason my R really doesn't like it when I upload XLSX files (the whole thing freezes and I have to CTRL+ALT+DLT to close R), so I only save and use .csv files. I used list.files() to check, but everything came back .csv